# Game of Life (html, javascript, css)

Tags: javascript

I have to create javascript code to solve the Game of Life.
I have some problem with my run() javascript function, with a while loop. Do you know, why?

I have the full exercise description in Hungarian only. If you need more information, please ask it! :)

This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Game of life</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="gameoflife.css">
<body>

<h1>Game of life</h1>
<form>
    <label>Size of the matrix [row x column]:</label>
    <select id="row" >
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20" selected>20</option>
    </select>
    <select id="column">
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20" selected>20</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" id="matrixButton" onclick="eptyMatrix()">Create an empty matrix</button>
</form>

<form id="matrix">
</form>

<script src="gameoflife.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the javascript:

```
var form = document.getElementById("matrix");
var row = 0;
var column = 0;

function emptyMatrix()
{
    var select1 = document.getElementById('row');
    row = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value;
    var select2 = document.getElementById('column');
    column = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;

    while (form.firstChild) {
        form.removeChild(form.lastChild);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (let j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            var ij = i.toString() + "|" + j.toString();
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
            input.setAttribute("id", ij);

            form.appendChild(input);
        }
        var linebreak = document.createElement("br");
        form.appendChild(linebreak);
    }

    baseStatement();

    var playButton = document.createElement("button");
    playButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
    playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
    playButton.setAttribute("onclick", "run()");
    form.appendChild(playButton);
}

function baseStatement() {
    for (let i = 1; i < row-1; i++)
    {
        for (let j = 1; j < column-1; j++) {
            var ij = i.toString() + "|" + j.toString();
            var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            if (num < 30) {
                document.getElementById(ij).checked = true;
            } 
        }
    }
}

function nextRound() {
    var matrix = new Array(row);
    for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new Array(column);
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < row-1; i++)
    {
        for (let j = 1; j < column-1; j++) {
            var ij = i.toString() + "|" + j.toString();
            if (document.getElementById(ij).checked == true){
                var neighborsNum = 0;
                for (let k = i-1; k <= i+1; k++)
                {
                    for (let l = j-1; l <= j+1; l++) {
                        var kl = k.toString() + "|" + l.toString();
                        if (document.getElementById(kl).checked == true) {
                            neighborsNum++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(neighborsNum-1 == 2 || neighborsNum-1 == 3)
                {
                    matrix[i][j] = true;
                }
                if(neighborsNum-1 != 2 && neighborsNum-1 != 3) {
                    matrix[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
            if (document.getElementById(ij).checked == false) {
                var neighborsNum = 0;
                for (let k = i-1; k <= i+1; k++)
                {
                    for (let l = j-1; l <= j+1; l++) {
                            var kl = k.toString() + "|" + l.toString();
                            if (document.getElementById(kl).checked == true) {
                                neighborsNum++;
                            }
                    }
                }
                if(neighborsNum == 3)
                {
                    matrix[i][j] = true;
                }
                if(neighborsNum != 3) 
                {
                    matrix[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < row-1; i++)
    {
        for (let j = 1; j < column-1; j++) {
            var ij = i.toString() + "|" + j.toString();
            document.getElementById(ij).checked = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}

function run() {
    setInterval(nextRound, 5000);
    //var hasChecked = true;
    //while(hasChecked == true){
    //    setTimeout(nextRound, 5000);
    //    hasChecked = false;
    //    checkMonitor:
    //    for(var i = 1; i < row-1; i++)
    //    {
    //        for(var j = 1; j < column-1; j++) {
    //            var ij = i.toString() + "|" + j.toString();
    //            if(document.getElementById(ij).checked == true){
    //                hasChecked = true;
    //                break checkMonitor;
    //            }
    //        }
    //    }
    //}
}
```

This is the css:

```
body {
  background-color : saddlebrown;
  font-family      : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color            : white;
  }
input:checked {
  accent-color : darkgreen;
  }
```

Many thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Please be more specific when you post a code this long. This will help others to focus on the problem that you are facing instead of debug the whole application. Thanks

Comment: `for (var j = 1; j < coulmn - 1; j++) { ` <-- typo maybe? `coulmn` should be `column`

Comment: Thanks, I changed where it was needed.

Answer (score 0):

I made that code, a long time ago...

```js
// activate ranges interface...
document
  .querySelectorAll('input[type=range]')
  .forEach(r => r.oninput =_=> r.closest('label').dataset.val=r.value)

const
  action = { run: false, cycle: 0 }
, size   = { cols: 0, rows:0 }
, onAction      = function* () { while(action.run) yield }
, delay         = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
, isAlive       = (r,c) => tbl.rows[r].cells[c].classList.contains('life')
, adjCellsCount = (row,col) =>
  {
  let res = 0
  for ( let r = Math.max(0, row-1); r < Math.min(size.rows, row+2); ++r )
  for ( let c = Math.max(0, col-1); c < Math.min(size.cols, col+2); ++c )
    if ((r!==row || c!==col) && isAlive(r,c) ) res++
  return res
  }
, StopGridAction =_=>
  {
  btClear.disabled = btGo.disabled = action.run = false
  btStop.disabled = !btGo.disabled
  tbl.className = 'onBorder'    
  }

cycles.onclick =_=>  // resset cycles count
  {
  cycles.textContent = action.cycle = 0
  } 
addPoints.onclick =_=>  // generate new life points
  {
  let 
    freePos = [...tbl.querySelectorAll('td:not([class="life"]')] 
  , ptN     = Math.min( freePos.length, Points.valueAsNumber )
    ;
  if (!ptN) return

  for (let i = freePos.length -1; i > 0; i--)  // shuffle Array
    {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [freePos[i], freePos[j]] = [freePos[j], freePos[i]]
    }
  for (;ptN--;) freePos[ptN].className = 'life'
  }
btDrawGrid.onclick = _ =>      // draw Grid Buttion
  {
  StopGridAction()
  tbl.innerHTML = ''  // clear Grid
  tbl.style.setProperty('--sz', cellSz.value + 'px')
  size.cols = nCols.valueAsNumber
  size.rows = nRows.valueAsNumber

  for ( let r = 0; r < size.rows; ++r) // build Grid 
    {
    let nRow = tbl.insertRow()
    for ( let c = 0; c < size.cols; ++c) nRow.insertCell()
    }
  addPoints.click()
  cycles.click()
  }
tbl.onclick = ({target}) =>  // add or remove points over Grid
  {
  if(!target.matches('td')) return
  // target.classList.toggle('life')
  target.className = target.classList.contains('life') ? '' : 'life';
  }

// first inits...
btStop.disabled = true
nCols.value     = 20
nRows.value     = 12
cellSz.value    = 16
Points.value    = 24

btDrawGrid.click()
addPoints.click()

// main parts...
btStop.onclick = StopGridAction  // stop Conway's Game of Life action
btClear.onclick =_=>  // clear Grid
  {
  tbl.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(el=>el.className = '')
  } 
btGo.onclick =_=>  // Start button -> see Conway's Game of Life action
  {
  gridOptions.open = false
  btClear.disabled = btGo.disabled = action.run = true
  btStop.disabled  = !btGo.disabled
  tbl.className    = ''
  loopLifes()
  }
async function loopLifes()
  {
  for await (x of onAction())
    {
    cycles.textContent = (++action.cycle).toLocaleString()
    await lifeCycle()
    await delay (300)
    tbl.querySelectorAll('td.die').forEach(el=>el.className = '')
    tbl.querySelectorAll('td.born').forEach(el=>el.className = 'life')
    await delay (800)
    }
  btStop.click()
  }

function lifeCycle()
  {
  return new Promise((successCallback) =>
    {
    let cLives = 0  // points counter
    for ( let r = 0; r < size.rows; ++r)
      {
      if ( !action.run ) break
      for ( let c = 0; c < size.cols; ++c) 
        {
        if ( !action.run ) break
        let aroundLife = adjCellsCount(r,c)
        if (isAlive(r,c))
          {
          if ( aroundLife < 2 || aroundLife > 3 )
            tbl.rows[r].cells[c].classList.add('die')
          else
            ++cLives
          }
        else
          {
          if (aroundLife === 3 ) 
            {
            tbl.rows[r].cells[c].className = 'born'
            ++cLives
      } } } }
    action.run &= Boolean(cLives)  // if there is no more live points
    successCallback()   
    })
  }
```

```css
table  {
  border-collapse  : collapse;
  margin           : 1em;
  background-color : white;
  }
table tbody {
  --sz : 12px;      
  }
table tbody td {
  width    : var(--sz);
  height   : var(--sz);
  border   : 1px solid transparent;
  position : relative;
  cursor   : pointer;
  }
table tbody td:hover {
  background-color : #28608371;
  }
table tbody:hover td,
table tbody.onBorder td {
  border-color : #d3d3d3cc;
  }
.born::before,
.die::before,
.life::before {
  position : absolute;
  content   : ' ';
  top       : 0;
  left      : 0;
  width      : 100%;
  height     : 100%;
  display      : inline-block;
  border-radius : 50%;
  }
.born::before { background-color : lightseagreen;        }
.die::before  { background-color : #f0808080 !important; }
.life::before { background-color : #286083;              }

body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  }
label {
  font-size : 12px;
  }
label input {
  vertical-align : middle;
  width          : 300px;
  }
label::after {
  content : ' ' attr(data-val);
  }
label::before {
  display : inline-block;
  width   : 4.5em;
  content : attr(data-lib);
  }
button {
  margin-top     : .4em; 
  min-width      : 4em;
  text-transform : capitalize;
  }
details {
  position      : absolute;
  top           : 1.7em;
  right         : .5em;
  width         : 7em;
  padding       : .4em .6em .3em .6em;
  background    : #286083e5;
  z-index       : 100;
  color         : white;
  border-radius : .4em;
  }
details[open] {
  width      : 24em;
  }
details label:first-of-type {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1.2em;
  }
summary {
  padding-right : .2em;
  text-align    : right;
  direction     : rtl;
  }
summary,
button:not(:disabled) {
  cursor : pointer;
  }
details button {
  float: right;
  }
mark {
  position      : absolute;
  top           : .4em;
  right         : .5em;
  width         : 7.6em;
  padding       : 0 .3em;
  text-align    : right;
  background    : none;
  cursor        : pointer;
  color         : darkgrey;
  border-radius : .2em;
  font-style    : oblique;
  }
mark:hover {
  background : #286083a2;
  color      : white;
  }
```

```html
<h3> Conway's Game of Life </h3>
<hr>
<details id="gridOptions">
  <summary>Grid options</summary>
  <label for="nCols" data-val="20" data-lib="Cols :" ><input type="range" id="nCols" min="6" max="60" value="20"></label> <br>
  <label for="nRows" data-val="12" data-lib="Rows :"><input type="range" id="nRows" min="6" max="60" value="12"></label> <br>
  <label for="cellSz" data-val="16" data-lib="size :"><input type="range" id="cellSz" min="6" max="40" value="16" style="width:100px;"></label><small>px</small> <br>
  <label for="Points" data-val="24" data-lib="Point(s) :"><input type="range" id="Points" min="1" max="50" value="24" style="width:240px;"></label><br>
  <button id="btDrawGrid"> draw grid </button>
</details>
<mark id="cycles">0</mark>
<button id="btGo"> go </button>
<button id="btStop"> stop  </button>
<button id="btClear"> clear </button>
<button id="addPoints"> Add Point(s) </button>
<table><tbody id="tbl" class="onBorder"></tbody></table>
```

Comment: @SaraPittner Since it was old code for me, I obviously needed to refactor it, make some fixes and slight improvements